# Corrupted original source file during copy-paste on Mac

Tags: filesystem, data-transfer, copy-paste, file-transfer

I was copying 100GB of essential documents from my Mac to my pen drive. I had to cancel the copy-paste operation because the process became stuck in the middle. The USB drive was accidentally ejected the second time.

My issue is: if I was transferring files from my Macbook and the copy process was canceled twice, will it affect the source files from which the data was copied? Are the original data destroyed or corrupted as a result of the copy-paste process being aborted and the pen drive being ejected in the middle? Because I have so many subfolders, I don't want my source files to be corrupted. Please assist me in persuading myself that canceling a copy-paste does not harm the source file on my Mac.

Comment: This is the third time you've asked the same question. How many times do you need people to tell you that you can't damage the original by interrupting the copy?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see a mechanism by which a read operation would cause the data on those files to be changed, even if interrupted.

But of course, for essential documents, you would have a at least one backup. (Bear in mind that cheap USB 'stick' drives are not always reliable and can suddenly fail.)